# How to pass selected key to another template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, charts

How to pass selected key to another template to display chart? I created a template which exports multi line chart, in which I have used Axios to get data from API.

In the home page I have created a dropdown, when a user selects an item then  the selected item or it's value to be passed to that chart template and that template should return chart to that selected item.

```html
// Home component
<template>
  <section>
    <label>City</label>
    <select @change="getArea()" v-model="key" class="custSelect2">
      <option :value="0">Select City</option>
      <option v-for="data in cityList" :value="data.id">{{ data.city }}</option>
    </select>

    <label>Area</label>

    <select @change="getWard()" v-model="keyArea" class="custSelect2">
      <option :value="0">Select Area</option>
      <option v-for="data in areaList" :value="data.id">{{ data.area}}</option>
    </select>

    <label>Ward</label>
    <select v-model="Polekey" @change="getPole()" class="custSelect2">
      <option :value="0">Select Ward</option>
      <option v-for="data in wardList" :value="data.id">{{ data.ward}}</option>
    </select>
    <label>Pole</label>
    <select v-model="PoleSelected" class="custSelect2">
      <option :value="0">Select Pole</option>
      <option v-for="data in PoleList" :value="data.poleid">{{ data.poleid}}</option>
    </select>
    <div>
      <Areachart />
    </div>
  </section>
</template>
```

```
// Area component
<script>
import { Line } from "vue-chartjs";

export default {
  extends: Line,
  data() {
    return {
      dataList: []
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    var self = this;

    axios
      .get("http://172.31.0.114:5008/api/city/data" + this.key) // key is the value that user selected
      .then(function(res) {
        self.dataList = res.data;
        // how to initilize data into below datasets
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error:", error);
      });

    this.renderChart(
      {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Data One",
            borderColor: "#FC2525",
            backgroundColor: this.gradient,
            data: []
          },
          {
            label: "Data Two",
            borderColor: "#05CBE1",
            data: []
          }
        ]
      },
      { responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false }
    );
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Pass `_key` via `props` (I assume it's type is `String` and it's required);
2. Watch `_key` changes and call `updateChart` method, so whenever parent changes `_key` the appropriate API cal is made;
3. Define `updateChart` method that sends `GET` request, handles it, and rerenders chart.
4. Call `updateChart` method in `mounted` hook to get initial data;
5. Define `datasets` in `data` so you can change them in subsequent
   server response handlers.
6. Dont forget to pass `_key` prop in the parent component.

```
// In ParentComponent
<template>
  <Areachart :_key="PoleSelected"/>
</template>

<script>
import { Line } from "vue-chartjs";

export default {
  extends: Line,
  props: {
    _key: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Data One",
          borderColor: "#FC2525",
          data: []
        },
        {
          label: "Data Two",
          borderColor: "#05CBE1",
          data: []
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  watch: {
    _key() {
      this.updateChart();
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.updateChart();
  },
  methods: {
    updateChart() {
      axios
        .get("http://172.31.0.114:5008/api/city/data" + this._key)
        .then(res => {
          // proccess the response
          // I don't know your data model, so i can't write appropriate handler
          // for example this.datasets[0].data = res.data[0]

          this.renderChart(
            {
              labels: [],
              datasets: this.datasets
            },
            { responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false }
          );
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log("Error:", error);
        });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: bro i have updated code please check it...i need to display chart after selecting pole in the dropdown menu.

Comment: @Pavan, Bro, updated the answer :). Just pass `data.poleId` as a `_key`.

Comment: after adding  :_key="data.poleId" inside <Areachart/> showing blank page.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'poleid' of undefined        ..............Property or method "data" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive

Comment: i declared poleid in data field.

Comment: Oh, I see, should be `data.poleid` instead of `data.poleId`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, should be `:_key="PoleSelected"`.

Comment: Can answer tomorrow's morning. Sorry, have to sleep.

Comment: @Pavan, where is your link?)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data via props in the component

```
<Areachart :data="values"/>
```

Or you can make an event bus and send the data with it. You can use $emit (sends the event) and $on (catches the event)

Comment: thank you for your response, please let me know How can i get that value in  the Areachart template and pass that value to my API.